# Wordpress ACF Repeater or While loop, make 1 variable holds all of the result data

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, while-loop, edit

I have this ACF reapeter code

```
$modalImages = array(); 
$mainID = get_the_ID();
if( have_rows('pop_up_images',$mainID) ):
    while ( have_rows('pop_up_images',$mainID) ) : the_row();
        $modalImages[] = get_sub_field('image_pop_up',$mainID);
    endwhile;
else :
endif;

var_dump($modalImages);
```

Thats what I tried so far, I added `$modalImages = array();` and a variable of `$modalImages[]` but the output is wrong, there are supposed to be 2 results, but it only shows 1 result.

Comment: Your loop looks ok to me. Have you tried `var_dump(get_fields($mainID));` before this code, to see if the 2 `pop_up_images` are there at that point? If so, have you tried `var_dump(get_sub_field('image_pop_up',$mainID));` after `the_row();` and got 2 results there too?

Comment: @FluffyKitten, Thanks to you I found out whats wrong, you are right, there's already a problem when I var_dump after the row and the code is correct. The problem was my settings on wordpress ACF repeater is wrong. Thank you

Comment: your loop works for me. can you show the backend with 2 records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You guys are right, the code is correct, the problem was my Wordpress ACF Repeater settings, Im not sure if this will help someone but here is the problem, the return format of my ACF Reapter was set to `Image Array` which should be `Image Url` in my case. I didnt realized this until someone pointed out that the code is correct so I checked my Settings. Thank you guys.